$ f: \mathbb{R}_{++}^n \to \mathbb{R} , f(x) =- \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^a \right)^{1/a}, a < 1, a \neq 0 $ is convex
Show that f is convex.
$ f: \mathbb{R}_{++}^n \to \mathbb{R} , f(x) =- \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^a \right)^{1/a}, a < 1, a \neq 0 $.
This is like a norm definition but with a < 1.
I tried to use Jensen's inequality but it does not lead anywhere. Same with Hessian matrix. Does anybody have a hint for that ?

Suppose $a\in(0,1)$. Take $c<0$. Then
$$
\{x: \ f(x) \le c\} = \{x : \ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^a \ge (-c)^a\}.
$$
The map $x\mapsto \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^a$ is concave, hence this set is convex. And $f$ is convex.
The same reasoning should work for $a<0$.

$t \mapsto -t^{1/a}$ is not convex  for 0 < a < 1,
also you showed nothing about a < 0

@user2614870 Here is another idea. Please check.

it seems correct
